# Issue with VSTS dashboard

Tags: azure-devops

I am adding the velocity widget to the VSTS dashboard for my project in order to show up the velocity data for each of the sprints. When I am configuring the widget, I am getting the following message:

> "Last time you checked.there were no results"

No data is showing up. Please help me with how to populate data into the velocity widget.

Comment: Can you attach a photo of your configuration?

Comment: As part of the configuration, under Work Items, I have selected the Work Item Type option with the value being "Product Backlog Item". For Velocity parameter, I have selected the value as "Count of work items". Also, I have selected both the advanced options : Display planned work for iterations and Highlight work completed late.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is no data for the widget to show. When you configuring the widget, you should be asked to select a Query as below:
[image]

The result of the Query is the data source for the widget. The message you see means that there is no work item returned by the query. So you just need to edit the configuration to select a correct query which returns the work items you want. If the listed queries does not meet your requirement, create a new query and then move it to Shared Queries.

Comment: While configuring the velocity widget, I am not able to see the Query option in the configuration window. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Shashidhar Can you share any screenshot and detailed steps?

Answer (score 0):

That means there aren’t related work items (Product Backlog Item you selected) in current sprint and old sprints that you specified for target team (number of iterations = old sprints count+ 1 (current sprint))

So, you need to check which one is the current sprint of specified team, then related work items in current sprints and old sprints. (Feature sprints won’t be included)

[image]